# React native hooks break hot reloading?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

Hot reloading works fine with class components but when it comes to function components with hooks such as `useState`, hot reloading resets its value.

Answer (score 3):

Hooks rely on the calling order to make sense.

> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html
>
> There is an internal list of “memory cells” associated with each component. They’re just JavaScript objects where we can put some data. When you call a Hook like useState(), it reads the current cell (or initializes it during the first render), and then moves the pointer to the next one. This is how multiple useState() calls each get independent local state.

---

> From https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader
>
> **Hook support**
>
> Hooks would be auto updated on HMR if they should be. There is only one condition for it - a non zero dependencies list.

```
❄️ useState(initialState); // will never updated (preserve state)
❄️ useEffect(effect); // no need to update, updated on every render
❄️ useEffect(effect, []); // "on mount" hook. "Not changing the past"
 useEffect(effect, [anyDep]); // would be updated

 useEffect(effect, ["hot"]); // the simplest way to make hook reloadable
```

> **To disable hooks reloading** - set configuration option:

```
import { setConfig } from 'react-hot-loader';

setConfig({
  reloadHooks: false,
});
```

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb but is there any way to `setConfig` as `react-hot-loader` package does not seem to be included in a `react-native cli` project

Comment: I've never worked with `react-native`. Can't help you with this one. Sorry.